# Select a number relative to another number

Tags: dart

Is there a better way (speed not needed, brevity and simplicity wanted) to achieve the following in less lines of code? (example below)

```dart
//    Example //
/*
 * Get Divisor For Number of Iterations - To Display Progress
*/
int fGetDivisor(int iMaxIters) {  
  int iDiv = 500;   // init
  if (iMaxIters >= 100000)
    iDiv = 20000;
  else if (iMaxIters > 20000)
    iDiv = 10000;
  else if (iMaxIters > 5000)
    iDiv = 2000;
  else if (iMaxIters > 2000)
    iDiv = 1000;

  return iDiv;
}
```

Comment: Isn't there an error in your code for `5000` and `10000` ?

Comment: Same question with conditions. The first is `>=` and other `>`. Is it wanted ?

Comment: It looks Ok to me, but you may be right. I cannot see what is wrong though. Perhaps the assignments could be better selections, but I cannot see an actual error. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `a ? b : c`  :

```dart
int fGetDivisor(int iMaxIters) =>
    iMaxIters >= 100000 ? 20000 :
    iMaxIters >   20000 ? 10000 :
    iMaxIters >    5000 ?  2000 :
    iMaxIters >    2000 ?  1000 :
                            500 ;
```

Or with a `Map<int,int>` to have the condition only in one place :

```dart
import 'dart:collection';

int fGetDivisor(int iMaxIters) {
  final map = new LinkedHashMap<int,int>()
    ..[99999] = 20000
    ..[20000] = 10000
    ..[ 5000] =  2000
    ..[ 2000] =  1000
    ;
  for (final step in map.keys) {
    if (iMaxIters > step) return map[step];
  }
  return 500;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think a ? b : c is probably the way to go, so I'll likely tick that thanks. It's brief, readable, simple and no-doubt plenty fast enough. I'm looking at something more generic also, so I may post that separately. Not that this is a big-deal, but elegant code is nice everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly I think those `firstWhere` ones make it just more complex.

This is the simplest I can come up with:

```dart
int fGetDivisor(int iMaxIters) {
  if (iMaxIters >= 100000) return 20000;
  if (iMaxIters > 20000) return 10000;
  if (iMaxIters > 5000) return 2000;
  if (iMaxIters > 2000) return 1000;
  return 500;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually for this type of code I like to use a list of keys and a list of values. The firstWhere method helps us out here as well:

```dart
int fGetDivisor(int iMaxIters) {
  var keys = [99999, 20000, 5000, 2000];
  var vals = [20000, 10000, 2000, 1000];

  var key = keys.firstWhere((e) => iMaxIters > e, orElse: () => null);
  return key == null ? 500 : vals[keys.indexOf(key)];
}
```

This approach also makes it easy to add new values to check against.

Comment: Thanks, that could be useful elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
int fGetDivisor(int iMaxIters) =>
  [[999999, 20000], [20000, 10000], [5000, 2000], [2000, 1000]]
    .firstWhere((x) => iMaxIters > x[0], orElse: () => [0, 500])[1];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll likely use that elsewhere.